# iTunes Connect - New App Upload Bug?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I attempted to submit my application for review, I got the following error message:

**"You must submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later. After you’ve submitted a build, select it in the Builds section below."**

However, after I do upload a new build and save/submit, I get the same error. Please note, it has been over an hour and still am getting the same error; also, it will not let me upload another build without incrementing the version number, which I do not want to do.

Any suggestions?